# Flutter: Text to Speech - No Sound in İOS

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I'm using flutter_tts package for text to speech. In android, everything is okay. It's works. But no sound in İOS. I don't know why. There is no error in console. It's very interesting i think. Here is my class code below.

```
class TextToSpeech {
  static FlutterTts tts = FlutterTts();

  static initTTS()async{
    await tts.setSharedInstance(true);
    tts.setIosAudioCategory(IosTextToSpeechAudioCategory.playAndRecord,
        [
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay,
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.duckOthers,
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth,
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP,
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers,
          IosTextToSpeechAudioCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker
        ],
        IosTextToSpeechAudioMode.voicePrompt
    );

    tts.setLanguage('en-US');
    tts.setSpeechRate(0.40);
    tts.setPitch(1.0);
    //tts.setVoice({"name": "Karen", "locale": "en-AU"});

  }
}
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me otherwise I will probably get cancer...

Comment: maybe you missing some steps while configuring?

Comment: like what dude?